# deploy WPF on windows 10 and 7 c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am working on a WPF application using visual studio 2015 on windows 10. the application is very simple, but I am not very good with WPF. 
the application works under:

> ```
>     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
> ```

and I want to deploy it to be working on both windows 7 and windows 10. 
but I cannot install any framework on windows 7 except the frameworks that come with the windows.

how to ensure that it is working on windows 7? and which .NET version should I use?
any tips could help. thank you

Comment: Usually editing the ,proj file will get it to work.  Create a dummy project on Window setting then edit existing project to use same setting as dummy.

Comment: okay thanks. but which with version of .net should I work?

Comment: The one that works on the PC you are using.

Comment: I am working on windows 10 and i want the application to work on windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do is to target .NET Framework 3.5 which is included in Windows 7 and supports WPF.  There really have not been that many changes to WPF since 3.5.  See this ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx ) for a history of .NET framework versions and the Windows versions they exist on.  you target a framework by selecting it on the Application tab of the properties page of each project.